# How do I find the Ad Unit Id in Google Ad Manager

Tags: google-ad-manager

I want to check the ad unit id for some banner ads in Google Ad Manager so I can display ads in my app, how do find it?

Answer (score 1):

After logging in to Ad Manager 360 click on

- 'Apps' in the left navigation
- the relevant app if you have multiple
- 'Ad units' in the top center navigation
- The Ad unit name  you want to get the id for
- 'Tags' in the top center navigation
- Select a tag type (for native apps this is Mobile application tag)

and voila you have the Ad unit ID you will need to use in your app